# Get photos for multiple tags with one API call

Tags: instagram-api

I use Instagram API (https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/mytag/media/recent?client_id=XXX) to get photos by tag. But I can get photos only for one tag.

How can i get by two or three tag? Could you help me with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get multiple tag result in one api call. You get tag results and merge them.

Answer (score 0):

You can foreach the tag and then join the result.